# Associative Tables in SQL, 2 primary keys

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am taking an introductory course on SQL and I'm stumped on one of our labs. For this lab, we get an ERD that we need to implement via SQL. The lab requires us to create two tables joined together with an associative table (SQL apparently doesn't like many to many relationships).

In this associative table, both attributes need to be primary keys and foreign keys (Pk, Fk) according the ERD. This doesn't make much sense to me (you can't have multiple primary keys) and thus have far I have been unable to implement the ERD by creating multiple primary keys in the table. Where I am going wrong here internet?

The code:

```
CREATE Table dbo.TargetMailingList
(
     TargetID INT NOT Null 
        Foreign Key References dbo.TargetCustomers(TargetID),

     MailingListsID INT Not NULL 
        Foreign Key References dbo.Mailinglists(MailingListID),

     Primary Key (MailingListID,TargetID), 
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a compound key, as stated by @Juru and create 2 foreign keys:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table_link
    (
    ndIdTable1 int NOT NULL,
    ndIdTable2 int NOT NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_link ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_Table_link PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    ndIdTable1,
    ndIdTable2
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_link ADD CONSTRAINT
    FK_Table_Table_1 FOREIGN KEY
    (
    ndIdTable1
    ) REFERENCES dbo.Table_1
    (
    ndIdTable1
    ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION 
     ON DELETE  NO ACTION 

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_link ADD CONSTRAINT
    FK_Table_Table_2 FOREIGN KEY
    (
    ndIdTable1
    ) REFERENCES dbo.Table_2
    (
    ndIdTable2
    ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION 
     ON DELETE  NO ACTION 

GO
```

Comment: Thank you over much for your help

Answer (score 4):

There are no two primary keys. It is a compound key. Both the columns are part of the same primary key. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key for more info.